# Working locally with remote spark context on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to work locally in python with a spark context of a remote EMR cluster(AWS).  I've set up the cluster but a locally defined SparkContext with remote master doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have experience with that? Working on a remote notebook is limited because you cannot create python modules and files. Working locally is limited due to computing resources. There is the option to SSH to the master node but then I cannot use a graphical IDE such as pyCharm

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"doesn't seem to work"_? I don't use PySpark, so I don't know, but I think it ought to work if you have the ports and addresses correctly set up. I'd use an SSH tunnel.

Comment: SparkContext(master=="spark://ip:port") doesn't work, it tells me the cluster is not found. `Failed to connect to master`

Comment: Try an SSH tunnel!

Comment: I used putty to connect using ssh to the cluster. Is this what you mean?

Comment: You can use PuTTY to create a tunnel between a local port and a remote port. Tunnel local `master_port` to remote `master_ip:master_port` like described [here](https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/). Then use `localhost` instead of `master_ip`:  `SparkContext(master='spark://localhost:port')`.

Comment: Which port to redirect is the question

Comment: Is it possible to create spark session using just the ip and port in spark session, without doing ssh to master node? Let me know you thoughts on it.